# How to pass wildcard in vue js post request?

Tags: javascript, laravel, routes, vue.js

How I can get the current wildcard id and pass it to my $http.post route in vue?

Once I created a quiz information it will return a page with a new url
http://localhost:8000/question/index/quiz/3

Then when I want to do a post route with a name 
Route::post('question/store/quiz/{quiz}');

Here is my Vue http request post method
this.$http.post('/question/store/'+ , input).then((response) => {

What will be id that I can pass after the + sign?

Comment: Are you using vue router?

Comment: No just a vue resource. What I did is to put an input type hidden then supply the quiz id in the value then I use jquery in my view just to get current quiz id.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is pretty hacky, but it'll work if your URLs are always going to be formatted like that. so what I'm doing here is using vanilla JS to get the URL pathname, parse the string by the `/` and turn it into an array, then grab the last index.

```
var locationString = location.pathname
var locationArray = locationString.split('/')
var quizId = locationArray[locationArray.length - 1];
```

The `quizId` variable is the wildcard you're looking for

You should note that this is going to break if you ever have any query parameters, such as a URL looking like: `/index/quiz/3?v=2842`